icarousel I have to remove the space coming above it. The cells come completely from the top first in swift
I have to remove the space coming above it. The cells come completely from the top first. Please tell me how it will be.
(https://i.sstatic.net/M6FbfF3p.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/M6FbfF3p.jpg)
class TableViewCardVC: UIViewController, iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate  {
@IBOutlet weak var carousel: iCarousel!

var dataitemcomponent : [TransitsDataItem] = []
var commonComponentModal : TransitsComponentModal!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configutaionTableView()
    getData()
}
func configutaionTableView(){
    carousel.type = .linear
    //carousel.dataSource = self
    //carousel.delegate = self
    carousel.isVertical = true
    carousel.isPagingEnabled = true
    carousel.bounces = false
    //carousel.reloadData()
}

func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    return dataitemcomponent.count
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
   
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self));
    switch String.getString(dataitemcomponent[index].componentType){
    case "image_text_card":

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "RightImageLeftTextComponentView", bundle: bundle);
        let cell = (nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! RightImageLeftTextComponentView);
        
        cell.lb_title.text = String.getString(dataitemcomponent[index].description)
        cell.lb_title.textColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: String.getString(dataitemcomponent[index].textColor))
        let url = URL(string: String.getString(dataitemcomponent[index].imageURL));
        cell.rightImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
        setLabelFontAndSpacing(label: cell.lb_title, fontName: "Lexend-Regular", fontSize: 16.0, lineSpacing: 5)
        cell.bgView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: String.getString(dataitemcomponent[index].cardColor))
        
        cell.lb_title.sizeToFit()
        let newHeight = cell.lb_title.frame.height + 80
        cell.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "CA8787")
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -300, width: cell.frame.width, height: newHeight)
        
        return cell
    case "color_card":
        
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ColorcardComponentView", bundle: bundle)
        let cell = (nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! ColorcardComponentView)
        cell.lb_title.text = String.getString(dataitemcomponent[index].description)
        cell.lb_title.textColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: String.getString(dataitemcomponent[index].textColor))
        setLabelFontAndSpacing(label: cell.lb_title, fontName: "Lexend-Regular", fontSize: 16.0, lineSpacing: 5)
        setLabelFontAndSpacing(label: cell.lb_title, fontName: "Lexend-Regular", fontSize: 16.0, lineSpacing: 5)
        cell.bgView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: String.getString(dataitemcomponent[index].cardColor))
        cell.lb_title.sizeToFit()
        let newHeight = cell.lb_title.frame.height + 80
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -300, width: cell.frame.width, height: newHeight)
        return cell
    case "paragraph":
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ParagraphComponentView", bundle: bundle)
        let cell = (nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! ParagraphComponentView)
        cell.lb_title.text = dataitemcomponent[index].description
        cell.lb_title.textColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: String.getString(dataitemcomponent[index].textColor))
        setLabelFontAndSpacing(label: cell.lb_title, fontName: "Lexend-Regular", fontSize: 16.0, lineSpacing: 5)
        cell.lb_title.font = UIFont(name: "Lexend-Regular", size: 16)
        cell.lb_title.sizeToFit()
        let newHeight = cell.lb_title.frame.height + 80
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -300, width: cell.frame.width, height: newHeight)
        
      return cell
    default:
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ParagraphComponentView", bundle: bundle);
        let cell = (nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! ParagraphComponentView);
        
        cell.lb_title.text = "In this article, I’d like to reacquaint you with the humble workhorse of communication that is the paragraph. Paragraphs are everywhere. In fact, at the high risk of stating the obvious, you are reading one now. Despite their ubiquity, we frequently neglect their presentation. This is a mistake.\n Your choice of font is important, but the kind of “family” you choose is project-specific, and we won’t discuss it here except to make one point: the conventional wisdom among Web designers that only sans-serif fonts are suitable for body text is just a rule of thumb. Although serif fonts, with their greater complexity. The offset multiplier to use when the user drags the carousel with their finger."
        cell.lb_title.font = UIFont(name: "Lexend-Regular", size: 16)
        cell.lb_title.sizeToFit()
        let newHeight = cell.lb_title.frame.height + 80
        
        cell.bgView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "B784B7")
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: newHeight)
        
        return cell
        
    }
}
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, itemTransformForOffset offset: CGFloat, baseTransform transform: CATransform3D) -> CATransform3D {
    //implement 'flip3D' style carousel
    let transformCopy = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(.pi / 8.0), 0.0, 0.5, 0.0)

    return CATransform3DTranslate (transformCopy, 0, 0, offset * carousel.itemWidth)
}
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    switch (option) {

    case .wrap:
        return 0

    case .fadeMin:
        return -0.4//-1.5

    case .fadeRange:
        return 1.0

    case .visibleItems:
        return 3.0

    case .fadeMax:
        return 0.4//1.0

    case .spacing:
        return 0.9

    default:
        return value
    }
}
func getData(){
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: String.getString("transit"), ofType: "json") else {
        print("JSON file 'HomeUP.json' not found in the bundle.")
        return
    }

    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        commonComponentModal = try decoder.decode(TransitsComponentModal.self, from: jsonData)
        dataitemcomponent = commonComponentModal.response.dataItems
        print("JSON data loaded successfully!")


        for dataItem in dataitemcomponent {
            //print("Type: \(dataItem.type), Display: \(dataItem.display)")
            // Do something with the filtered items
        }
        carousel.delegate = self
        carousel.dataSource = self
        carousel.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print("Error reading JSON data: \(error)")
    }
}

}
Please tell me how it will be.
